# Receiving packets from any protocol on a raw linux socket

Tags: c#, c++, linux, sockets, ip

I would like to create an IP tunnel. For that, I create a raw socket in C# on the client and bind it to port 4999:

```
Socket mysock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
mysock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 4999));
mysock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 4999));
```

Now I can just call `mysock.Receive(byte[])`, and I get all the IP packets, including the IP header. For example, if I try to open a TCP connection to `127.0.0.1:4999`, the C# application captures 3 packets. I can also send packets over this socket and it will work just fine.

The C# application then transfers those packets to a C++ application running on a linux machine. There, I change the sender port (that's the easy part, just write it into the TCP header) and then I would like to simply send it out and have everything else done for me, just like it works in C#. And obviously, I would also like to receive packets from the raw linux socket, so I can transfer them back to the C# application and get some communication going.

I have already implemented *everything except the raw linux socket*. **That's my question**: How can I write the above C# code in C/C++ for linux? According to [raw(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw), I won't get TCP or UDP packets if I just do `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)`, right?

Edit: By the way, I'm running the C# code on windows but that is not my problem.

Comment: Berkeley Sockets would be the preferred option for C IMHO http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/sockets.html if you're using C++, libraries such as Boost have wrappers around Berkeley that are closer to the C# code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The port number should not be the TCP or UDP port number in this case.

It should be (I'm not sure) the higher-level protocol identifier (e.g. a "port number" of 6 means: TCP packets while 17 means: UDP packets). The current Linux version says the port number must be 0 for raw sockets. "root" rights are required for the application.

Differences in **Windows** (compared to Linux):

The Windows documentation says that raw sockets are allowed for ICMP and IGMP packets (only).

Using the winpcap library should allow a program to get raw access to an Ethernet card. However you'll also see the 14 byte Ethernet header (before the IP header) in this case and you'll receive all kinds of Ethernet packets (in a normal TCP/IP network these should be ARP, IPv4, IPv6 and STP) and not only IPv4 packets.

There is a .NET wrapper for winpcap so you should be able to use winpcap with C#, too.

Comment: You are talking about the protocol identifiers. But I would like to be able to transfer IP packets without caring about the transport layer.

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstod my question. The Windows part works perfectly fine, I just need help with the Linux part.